# Reporting non-causal relationships

Tags: regression, causality, reporting

What is the appropriate way of reporting significant regression coefficients of a multiple regression when all variables have been obtained at the same measurement occasion? Specifically, do I imply a causal relationship when I report that A significantly predicts B or A has a significant effect on B?

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way is to make sure your language *doesn't* imply causality that isn't there. Reporting that A significantly predicts B, or that there is a strong association between A and B doesn't imply any causal direction.

Your second report example, "A has a significant effect on B", does in my mind. So unless there's another credible reason to assert the direction of the relationship is A acts on B, I'd stay away from it.